# How to set the config-name parameter in Omnetpp.ini?

Tags: omnet++, ini

I have an omnetpp.ini file structured as follows:

***[General]***

***// Set of parameter initializations ...***

***[Config Test]***

***// Set of other parameter initializations ...***

Before starting a simulation, Omnetpp asks to precise the config-name (either General or Test).
So how to set the Test config-name as default?

Since I'm simulating heavy scenarios, I'm deactivating the Omnetpp GUI (to accelerate simulations). Therefore I can't set the config-name to Test. Is there any way to set it in the .ini file?

Answer (score 0):

In OMNeT++ go to `Run` | `Run Configurations...` | choose your configuration, then in `Config name:` set `Test`. Next time `Test` config will be chosen by default.